# How to join the Snowflake stored procedure result with a table

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I'm trying to join the table resultset returned from a stored procedure to a table in snowflake.

The methods that I tried :

Method #1:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_result AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM TABLE(execute_sql_from_sp())
);
```

Method #2:

```
WITH sp_result AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM TABLE(execute_sql_from_table())
)
SELECT t.column1, t.column2, sp_result.column3
FROM your_table t
JOIN sp_result ON t.id = sp_result.id;
```

None of these work. Any ideas on how we can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the doc's [Stored Procedure's results are not inline available](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/stored-procedures-vs-udfs#udf-return-values-are-directly-usable-in-sql-stored-procedure-return-values-may-not-be):

So you have to do it indirectly.

1. The stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure FIRST_PROC()
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT 
AS
$$
    A = 'DONE';
    return A;
$$;
```

2. call it

```
call first_proc();
```

3. fetch the results via [RESULT_SCAN](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/result_scan) and LAST_QUERY_ID

```
select * from table(result_scan(last_query_id()));
```

4. profit!

[image]